# Cannot debug C++ in Visual studio 2013 once I set common language runtime support

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio 2013. I put the following three lines in my code. For it to compile, I go to the project properties and enable common language runtime support.

```
using namespace System;
#using <System.Xml.dll>
using namespace System::Xml;
```

I can build the project with no errors. But if I put a breakpoint anywhere, the code does not break there. Instead, after I start the code, for a short moment, a red circle (with white inside) and a very small exclamation mark on the side appears in place of the full red circle.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The updated managed debugging engine in VS2013 is no longer compatible with C++/CLI.  Use Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" option.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. My solution has two projects inside. I had to enable common language runtime support for both projects. Once I did that, things started to work as normal.

Comment: Don't just arbitrarily change project options like that, that's awful.  Ensure the debugger can handle both flavors of code.  Right click the startup project > Properties > Debugging > Debugger Type = Mixed.

Comment: @Hans Passant, Thanks a lot for your input. I followed your direction and there was no need to enable common language runtime for the startup project. Your comment was the answer to my question.